# Android M Run time Permission issue

Tags: android, bitmap, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, video-thumbnails

I have search a lot about this problem but i didn't find any solution why this happening?

Currently i have face strange problem with run time permission ,i'm trying to ask runtime permission for camera and it's work fine but my problem is when user allow the permission my code for pick video from gallery and make thumbnail with ThumbnailUtils but it will return null once when my app is install first time i mean when user first time allow for permission it will return null after all the cases thumbnailutil works fine,As well as below android M its work fine for first time too.

**What I'm currently doing is**

Ask for appropriate permission and after check allow or deny further i process for select video from gallery as per my requirement

-----------------Camera Permission-----------------

```
 public void requestPermissionForCamera() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Camera permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

-----------------External Storage permission--------------------

```
  public void requestPermissionForExternalStorage() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "External Storage permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

Below is my onRequestPermissionsResult & onActivityResult

**UPDATE:**

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


             //   my code for open video or image gallery
            } else {
                //SnackBar  "The app was not allowed to write to your storage. Hence, it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it this permission"
            }
        }
    }

}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == FragmentActivity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) {

            Uri videoUri = data.getData();
            selectedVideoPath = getRealPathFromURI(videoUri);

            if (selectedVideoPath == null) {
                Log.e("vediotag", "selected video path = null" + selectedVideoPath);

            } else {
                Log.e("vediotag", "selected video path----" + selectedVideoPath);

            //create video thumbnail
                Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(selectedVideoPath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                insertData(mimageTitle, bitmap, selectedVideoPath);

            }
        }
    }

}


public String getRealPathFromURI(final Uri contentURI) {
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        return contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        if (idx == -1) {
            return contentURI.getPath();
        }
        String rvalue = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
        return rvalue;
    }
}
```

**Problem Which i'm currently facing**

Above my code is working fine after activity recreate once,but it fail for the first time when i have install app and allow for permission.

> NOTE:
>    I don't want to recreate activity programmatically so don't suggest me for doing that.

Any help will be much appreciated

Regards.

Comment: any error from logcat?

Comment: Nope there is not error or not crash but thumbnail util return me the null bitmap for once.

Comment: show complete class..where you request permission and its onRequestPermissionsResult()

Comment: There is nothing wrong inside onRequestPermissionsResult() i have handle it properly no need to show full class code not required i think but fine lemme update it with onRequestPermissionsResult()

Comment: It would be better to user EasyPermission for implementing and maintaining Runtime permission model : https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions